# XML files to treeview how to bind so that i will get the desired result

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

i have xml file

1
        Positive Feedback
        2
        Positive Feedback - Inflight
        1
        Flight Attendants
        1
      
      
        1
        Positive Feedback
        5
        Positive Feedback - Other
        1
        Other
        1
      
      
        3
        Flight Operations
        1
        Flight Paperwork
        1
        Flight Paperwork details
        2
      
      
        3
        Flight Operations
        4
        Flight Crew Manuals
        8
        Vol. 2
        1
      
      
        3
        Flight Operations
        15
        Chief Pilot Office / Chief Pilot Support Center
        1
        Chief Pilot Office
        1
      
      
        3
        Flight Operations
        15
        Chief Pilot Office / Chief Pilot Support Center
        2
        Chief Pilot Support Center
        1
      
      
        4
        Inflight Services
        1
        Catering
        1
        Passenger Catering
        1
      
      
        4
        Inflight Services
        2
        Other Inflight Item
        1
        Other Inflight Item details
        2
      
      
        7
        Security
        3
        Passenger Security 
        4
        Other Passenger Security Issues
        2

i have to bind into tree view so that result sould be like

toipc--'Category1--'Subcategory11
       '           'subcategory12
       '
       'category2--'Subcategory21
                   'Subcategory22

how can i do it

Comment: If your xml is structured correctly then you can use an xmldatasource to bind to a treeview

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to the following link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134102/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042308-1.aspx